# Why is my XMLHttpRequest progress console log not showing?

Tags: javascript, ajax, react-native, file-upload, xmlhttprequest

The progess of the file upload is not being console logged. Why?

Here is the code I have:

```js
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    
xhr.open('POST', apiUrl);

xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(e){
    console.log(e.loaded/e.total)      
})

xhr.onload = () => {
    const response = JSON.parse(xhr.response);
    console.log(response);
    // ... do something with the successful response
};
        
xhr.send(formData);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `apiUrl` response must have the HTTP response header `Content-Length`. If it doesn't, there is nothing to compute.

Maybe the event handler should be bound to `xhr`:

```js
xhr.addEventListener("progress", function(e) {
```